# Invalid resource directory name when making icon for locale

Tags: android

This is probably a very basic problem but I am very new to Android development and I can't find a a reason why this isn't working. I am just testing icons for different locales and I keep getting

`/home/isaac/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi-en-rUS: Error: Invalid resource directory name`

But as far as I can tell from [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) (see Table 2 "Language and region"), I seem to have it specified correctly, appending `-en-rUS` to the folders with a different icon in them. It even looks right in Android Studio:

[image]

And also in the folder structure for my `res` folder:

```
isaac@ib:~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/res$ tree
.
├── drawable
│   └── ic_launcher_background.xml
├── drawable-anydpi
├── drawable-v24
│   └── ic_launcher_foreground.xml
├── layout
│   ├── activity_display_message.xml
│   └── activity_main.xml
├── mipmap-anydpi-v26
│   ├── ic_launcher_round.xml
│   └── ic_launcher.xml
├── mipmap-anydpi-v26-en-rUS
│   ├── ic_launcher_round.xml
│   └── ic_launcher.xml
├── mipmap-hdpi
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-hdpi-en-rUS
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-mdpi
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-mdpi-en-rUS
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-xhdpi-en-rUS
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-xxhdpi-en-rUS
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-xxxhdpi
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── mipmap-xxxhdpi-en-rUS
│   ├── ic_launcher_foreground.png
│   ├── ic_launcher.png
│   └── ic_launcher_round.png
├── values
│   ├── colors.xml
│   ├── ic_launcher_background.xml
│   ├── strings.xml
│   └── styles.xml
└── values-land
    └── colors.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mipmap-hdpi-en-rUS: This is invalid res directory.

mipmap-hdpi is valid.

we add qualifiers like locale qualifiers for values folders not mipmap folders.

Suppose we have string resources we want them to provide different for different locales so we use qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-lang and r18n supports mipmap, your directories would look like this.

[image]

If you have other annotation that you wanna include in the directory's name, please refer to official doc for correct orders

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2